# Save a window to an image file

Tags: python, wxpython, jpeg

I was reading "wxpython in action" and found a paintwindow demo in the book. It saves its data using cpickle(*.paint). I would like to know how to save the data in the window as a jpg file, so i can view it with a standard image viewer.

**saveas function in the book:**

```
def OnSaveAs(self, event):
        file_wildcard = "Paint files(*.paint)|*.paint|All files(*.*)|*.*"
        dlg = wx.FileDialog(self, "save paint as ...", os.getcwd(), style=wx.SAVE|wx.OVERWRITE_PROMPT, wildcard=file_wildcard)
        if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            filename = dlg.GetPath()
            if not os.path.splitext(filename[1]):
                filename += ".paint"
            self.filename = filename
            self.SaveFile()
            self.SetTitle(self.Title + " -- " + self.filename)
        dlg.Destroy()

def SaveFile(self):
    if self.filename:
        data = self.paint.GetLinesData()
        f = open(self.filename, "w")
        cPickle.dump(data, f)
        f.close
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a tutorial on how to take a screenshot of your application using wxPython a while ago: http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/04/16/how-to-take-a-screenshot-of-your-wxpython-app-and-print-it/

You probably won't want the entire window, so you'll probably need to calculate your panel's size or perhaps your drawing's size in relation to the sides of the frame. But the rest of the code in that example should get you started.